# C# Gauss-Boaga Roma40 to WGS84

Tags: c#, .net, coordinates

I would convert in C# function coordinates like these:

Long -> 2425828.5
Lati -> 4749990
EST

To

Long -> 13.8464995897952
Lati -> 42.8965776073081

Hope, anyone can help me thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a GPS coordinate which need to be converted to LAT and LONG . For LAT use : lat = (90 * number) / 162000000.0;.  for LONG : lon = (180 * number) / 324000000.0;

Comment: Thnks fro the response but if i calculate lat and lon with your formule the result is not correct; es: LAT = (90 * 4749990.0) / 162000000.0 = 2.6388833333 insted of this 42.8965776073081.

Comment: See following : http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/conversion-from-Gauss-Boaga-Roma40-to-WGS84-constant-offset-td5219131.html

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand, in your link i view a Java source code and use a tool Geotool but i can't find in nuget library for my project c#. Can you explain me an example to calculate the conversion?

Comment: The link says there is a fixed offset.  The Gauss Boaga Roma-40 looks like an Italian standard and I can't understand most of the comments.